# Как передать в метакласс параметры в момент его вызова?

Tags: python, классы, metaclass

Стоит задача следующим образом: в зависимости от передаваемых параметров, класс должен принимать конкретный метакласс. Как это реализовать - идей нет. Буду благодарен за какие-либо подсказки.

Comment: Довольно подробно все расписано https://habr.com/ru/post/65625/

Comment: Я читал этот пост, ответа на мой вопрос там нет.

Comment: И этот пост тоже читали? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762231/how-to-pass-arguments-to-the-metaclass-from-the-class-definition

Comment: Уже ближе к правде. Но мне допустим необходимо передавать аргументы при создании экземпляра класса. То есть условно есть `example = some_class(*args, **kwargs)` , а в some_class есть __metaclass__. И хотелось бы, чтобы *args и **kwargs передавались в этот метакласс.